# Error C: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm new at programming in C language and I'm trying to do a program which adds ellipsis in every space I have in a table, which contains some text.
I don't know why I get that error I told you on the title and it's imposible for me to find the problem.

Before the code I only have set this:

```
char string1, string2;
```

```
int ellipsis(string1, string2)
{
    int m, n, tan, blanks;
    tan=strlen(string1);
    blanks = 0;
    n=0;
    for(m=0; m<tan; m++)
        if (string1[m] != ' ')   //<-----The program says that the error is in this line.
        {
          string2[n] = string1[m];
          n++;
        }
        else
        {
            blanks++;
            string2[n] = '.';
            string2[n+1] = '.';
            string2[n+2] = '.';
            n+=2;
        }
    string2[n] = '\0';
    return blanks
}
```

Comment: what is `string1` ? you need to show _all_ the code

Comment: `char string1` is a variable for a single character, not for a string. You would need something like `char string1[20]` (if you want to hold strings up to 19 characters). The function definition `int ellipsis(string1, string2)` should specify the types of the parameters. Otherwise the default type is `int` which is not an array or pointer.

Comment: if `char string1, string2;` appears outside your function, as you seem to be saying, and your function declares parameters `string1` and `string2`, as shown, then the `string1` and `string2` outside the function have nothing to do with those inside the function.

Comment: Also, you should be getting some warnings from your compiler in addition to the error.  If you're not, then turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.  Then *pay attention to those warnings*.